# Auto Complete feature in C# win forms dynamic

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I am new to C# programming and I trying to develop a small app which will help me search through all the tests that we have. 
So I have a search box, and a button. So whatever I type in the search box I pass that using button_click method to do a contains against a list which contains all the tests. based on the match it spits out the results. Simple!

So what I thought I could use this list to create a nice auto complete feature. UI found that there is autocomplete property in Win forms. However I am struggling to figure out a way in which I can pass the list from C# into the win forms design view and make it use it.
One can hard code the list of of all the items, and it works like a charm, but I want to make it loosely coupled.

Comment: Set up auto complete with custom source for a `TextBox`. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: @ Reza Aghaei can you elaborate on that? Like where should I put the code? sorry for but I come from java background and all of this is new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can config a `TextBox` to use a custom source for auto complete:

- Set [`AutoCompleteMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode(v=vs.110).aspx) property of a `TextBox` to [`Suggest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletemode(v=vs.110).aspx), `Append` or `SuggestAppend`
- Set [`AutoCompleteSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aehe18z8(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `CustomSource`.
- Assign a custom source to [`AutoCompleteCustomSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `TextBox`.

**Example**

In the below example, I set list of month names as auto complete source. You can use any `string[]` as auto complete custom source.

```
textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
source.AddRange(System.Globalization.CultureInfo
                      .InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames);
textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
```